# Reduce output image uri size from gt::ggplot_image()

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, google-slides-api, gt

Does anyone happen to have any good tips or tricks for reducing the image URI size output by `gt::ggplot_image()`?  I am using a python script to send plots to Google Slides and everything is working as expected, except the URI for image replacements is too large. Here's a reprex of my issue:

```
# create plot
my_plot <- ggplot(iris) + geom_histogram(aes(x = Sepal.Width)

# create image uri from plot
my_plot_image <- gt::ggplot_image(my_plot))

# check size of image uri (needs to be 2k bytes or less)
object.size(my_plot_image) # 21384 bytes
```

I port in the following python function using the `reticulate` package, so I imagine it might also be possible to either create or modify the image URI using python instead:

```
def request_slide_image_insert(placeholder_txt, img_uri):
    return dict(replaceAllShapesWithImage={
      "containsText": {
          "text": "{{" + placeholder_txt + "}}",
          "matchCase": False
      },
      "imageUrl": img_uri
    })
```

This gets used in the final script as follows:

```
# works with external placeholder image
request_slide_image_insert("placeholder_in_template", "https://picsum.photos/100/100")

# fails with ggplot uri
request_slide_image_insert("placeholder_in_template", my_plot_image)
```

Error message:

> "Invalid requests[20].replaceAllShapesWithImage: The URL must be 2K bytes or less.". Details: "Invalid requests[20].replaceAllShapesWithImage: The URL must be 2K bytes or less."

Comment: Reduce the `height` argument. By default it is 100. If you drop to 90 it should fall below 2K

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to make any noticeable impact... even setting the height to 1 only reduces the size to 21376 bytes :(

Comment: Although unfortunately, I cannot confirm your script for authorizing scopes and requesting Google Slides API, in order to reduce the image size, I think that if you can use Drive API, your goal can be achieved. To use Drive API is included in your expected direction?